# Combine nav and jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to combine the navigation and jumbotron `div`s so that both can encompass the whole page (`100vh`) and not go further. Essentially, I want both the navigation and jumbotron, but I want the elements to fill up the whole page without it being scrollable.

Currently, the navigation has a fixed height and so does the jumbotron. Take a look at it here (https://jsfiddle.net/orna9gz8/), although JSFiddle doesn't have a big enough screen to see that everything goes beyond the page. Some things I tried, but didn't work:

- I tried removing the default Bootstrap margin between the navigation and jumbotron, but there the jumbotron still goes beyond the page.
- I tried setting `margin-top` to `-10%` and this solved the issue temporarily (everything now fits on one page), but this doesn't seem to be working on smaller devices. This is probably not a mobile-friendly/responsive solution.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Nav links -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="teams.html">Teams</a></li>
                    <li><a href="involved.html">Get Involved</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
    <div class="container text-center" id="landing">
        <h1>Website</h1><br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu placerat eros, sed interdum lectus.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    background: none;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the navbar fixed, remove the `.jumbotron` margin and make it `min-height:100vh`

https://jsfiddle.net/rf4Lj4y9/

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    background: none;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

PS - your fiddle has the CSS in the JavaScript editor.